# write html to client on the fly in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, post, client, server

I'm writing a web app with node.js and I'm using socket.io to recieve information about user decisions on the client-side to my server.

After recieving this information i want to inject relevant html to the client.

How do I do that?

```
module.exports = function(io) {
    var http = require('http');
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log('We have Lift-off!');
        socket.emit('connect', { msg: 'We have Lift-off!' });

        //ppc action
        socket.on('ppc-action', function (data) {
            console.log(data.action);
            if (data.action === 'creation') {
                //write html to body
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: send a socket.emit and then catch it with client JS and then manipulate the DOM or do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Nada, That's what im basically doing, sending all the html as JSON with socket.emit and catching it with the client. i just thought there was an easier way